# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I using Android Studio, this error occur. sad..
I'm trying a lot of things but It doesn't work.

This is error code.

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
```

This is build.gradle (Module: app)

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
   compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.landmarkclass"
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 30
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"

   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision'

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision'

}
```

This is build.gradle Project

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
}

ext {
   compileSdkVersion = 28
   supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"

}
```

Thank you!

(
I wanted to follow this site,( https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-landmarks ) but this error occurs.
)

Answer (score 0):

This is because that you are using both **Play services ml service** and **firebase ml library**. If your requirement is only this one:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-landmarks

Remove this dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision'
```

And then sync and run. Hope this will work.